# How to configure Virtualbox internal network if client and server both have the same IP?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I'm just looking for whether the scenario I'm attempting to get to is even possible, if not, I know what I have to do, although I'd rather avoid it.

I'm using W10 and Virtualbox with both Ubuntu and Ubuntu Server installed. Now, the scenario I want to get working is the following:

**W10 -> ssh -> Ubuntu (client) -> ssh -> Ubuntu server (server)**

W10 -> ssh -> client Ubuntu works fine using lo1 of 127.0.0.1 //// Also want Ubuntu client to have access to the host LAN

Ubuntu client -> ssh -> server does **not** work as client and server both have the same IP.

Things I've tried / realise:

- NAT is giving both VMs the same IP, yet if I remove this, or add an internal network, ubuntu client no longer has access to W10 host machine's LAN
- As soon as I add an internal network adaptor to ubuntu client, I can no longer SSH into it from W10 (which I wish to do due to writing my code there, then ssh'ing with VSCode into said Ubuntu client)
- Tried to set up a DHCP server on the client and this worked fine, yet it wouldn't assign an IP to the Ubuntu server VM even though its Virtualbox adaptor internal network name is the **exact same**

Have read plenty of posts and used various guides, yet it feels like this situation only happens because I don't have dual-boot Linux and wish to work from w10. Also do not have space to install Ubuntu and thus, don't consider it an option for a project that'll take 14 days tops.

So can anyone confirm or deny whether this is possible and if so, point me in the right direction?

As I'm simply looking for a confirm/deny here I haven't added any specifics. If needed, I'll naturally add them in.

Comment: Note the Ubuntu server OS, is just Ubuntu with the windowing system not installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

127.0.0.1 should not take you to another machine (virtual or not), I don't know what is happening there (could be: port forwarding, miss-reporting what is happening, or something strange).

To get it to work, every device needs its own IP address. Give your virtual machines two network adaptors. One set as nat (this will give simple access to the internet: outgoing connections). One set as Host only (I don't get the name this is Host + Internal). Use the host network to communicate between machines.

Your virtual machines will now have 2 IP addresses. However you only need to consider the one for the host network.

Comment: thank you! how do i mark this as the answer? pretty new to this site : /

Comment: click the tick ✓ It is just under the up/down voting arrows.

Comment: wanted to follow up, i ended up getting it to work through having 2 network adapters active on my client, one with NAT and port forwarding setup (hence the lo1 working to ssh into it from my windows host) and the other one with NAT network.

added a NAT network to the server VM as well and voila, both VMs have IPs assigned by the host machine. 

would like again to say how useful your comment regarding 'Host only' network adapters was. Didn't understand that it included internal as well.